# What does "I've been for you" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, passive-voice, interpretation

This a stanza from the song 
[Talkin' karate blues by Townes Van Zandt](http://ippc2.orst.edu/coopl/lyrics/tvz_016.html):

> I said, "I believe I better go check another place"
>   he said, "Ha so, Yankee don't like my race"
>   I said, "Now there's a mistake man, and that's true
>   ***I've been for you*** you japanese all along
>   you japanese just can't do no wrong
>   and I thought you got mighty dirty deal in World War II."

But I'm not sure what it means. After that *been* is there any hidden verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an idiom: to be *for* someone is to be on that person's side, to cheer for that person's success. It's opposite has the same structure: to be *against* somebody is to be opposed to that person, to hope that person fails.

Comment: so, is he saying that he agrees with what the teacher said?
I'm note sure if he is with the teacher in question of opinion or not being a racist.

Comment: He is disagreeing with the teacher's statement that TVZ "don't like my race". On the contrary, says TVZ, I was for you Japanese all along.